# undefined reference when compiling the driver with shared library file

Tags: shared-library

I made a simple memory manger and I'm trying to compile it using shared library in the driver.

The shared library files itself compiles fine. However, when I compiled the driver by calling the functions in the shared library with my memory manager, it shows me the screenshot below:[image: error messages]

Here are my code for the shared.c

```
/* conveniences for casting and declarations */
typedef block_info* (*MM_CREATE)(size_t, MMPolicy);
typedef void* (*MM_ALLOCATE)(block_info *, size_t, char *);
typedef int (*MM_DEALLOCATE)(block_info *, void *);
typedef void (*MM_DESTROY)(block_info *);

/* Function pointers retrieved from the shared library */
typedef struct LibraryFunctions
{
   MM_CREATE create;
   MM_DESTROY destroy;
   MM_ALLOCATE allocate;
   MM_DEALLOCATE deallocate;
}LibraryFunctions;

/* Loads a shared library and returns a pointer to it in libhandle */

/* Returns SUCCESS, if it successful, otherwise, FAILURE           */
int load_library(const char *libname, void **libhandle)
{

*libhandle = dlopen(*libhandle, RTLD_LAZY);

if(!(*libhandle))
{
    return FAILURE;
}
else
{
    return SUCCESS;
}

return *libname;
}
int get_functions(void *libhandle, 
               LibraryFunctions *functions, 
               const char **fn_names)
{
functions->create = (MM_CREATE)(intptr_t)dlsym(libhandle, *fn_names);

if(!functions->create)
{
    return FAILURE;
}

functions->destroy = (MM_DESTROY)(intptr_t)dlsym(libhandle, *fn_names);

if(!functions->destroy)
{
    return FAILURE;
}

functions->allocate = (MM_ALLOCATE)(intptr_t)dlsym(libhandle, *fn_names);

if(!functions->allocate)
{
    return FAILURE;
}

functions->deallocate = (MM_DEALLOCATE)(intptr_t)dlsym(libhandle, *fn_names);

if(!functions->deallocate)
{
    return FAILURE;
}

return SUCCESS;
```

}
Here is part of the driver code to call the shared library:

```
void setup(void)
{
  const char *fn_names[] = {"mm_create", "mm_destroy", "mm_allocate",   "mm_deallocate"};
  LibraryFunctions funs;
  int error;

  error = load_library("./libmemmgr.so", &gLib);
  if (error == FAILURE)
  {
    printf("load_library failed! %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(-1);
  }

  error = get_functions(gLib, &funs, fn_names);
  if (error == FAILURE)
  {
    printf("get_functions failed! %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(-1);
  }

  mmlib_create = funs.create;
  mmlib_destroy = funs.destroy;
  mmlib_allocate = funs.allocate;
  mmlib_deallocate = funs.deallocate;
```

}

```
void teardown(void)
{
  dlclose(gLib);
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the errors.

edit: So I managed to run the exe file but I failed on "get_functions". Are there any problems with my get_functions?

Comment: add ` -ldl` to your compilation if not already included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be linking against the `dl` library, where `dlclose` and `dlerror` are defined (at least on Linux).

You're also not linking against your own shared library, where you defined the function `load_library`.  You don't show the code that defines `get_functions` at all, so I'm not sure where that lives.

So: your shared library should be named `libfoo.so`, and you need to add `-L. -lfoo -ldl` to your compiler command line, after all the `.c` files.  The `-L.` will tell the compiler to add the current directory to the library search path, the `-lfoo` will tell it to link against the `libfoo.so` from the current directory, and the `-ldl` will tell it to also link against a `libdl.so` somewhere else in the library search path (probably /usr/lib).

Comment: I updated the code that include the "get_functions" function.

Comment: I followed your instructions and added -L. -lfoo -ldl. Now the dl errors are gone. But I still can't access those two functions.@godlygeek